# Read a .jdx file in R

Tags: r

I want to read a `*.jdx` file wit the `readJDX` package in R.

```
install.packages("readJDX")
library(readJDX)
spectra <- readJDX(file = "2.jdx")
```

I get the error message:

> ```
> Couldn't find any variable lists. Supported formats are: XYY, XRR, XII, NMR_2D
> ```

The file looks like this

```
##TITLE=Unnamed Substance
##JCAMP-DX=4.24
(...)
##$WAVELENGTHCOEFFICIENTS=1841.9230100675625 -0.9200946785164401 -0.00023378830095489408 
##XYPOINTS=(XY..XY)
900.80 9289
903.43 19578
904.74 4041
906.05 -10553
(...)

##END=
```

Comment: This is already answered on the github issue [page](https://github.com/bryanhanson/readJDX/issues).